# How would I have my program calculate two equations from one input field?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, events, equation-solving

I need two functions to be calculated from the user and wanted to know how I would use the same input field to display in an dialog box both answers when it is done. I am in the fourth week of my comp sci class and I feel like I have dove into a bit of trouble. We were asked to do this program using the JOptionPane but I wanted to do a little more and created my own.

What I have done so far, the program has compiled correctly in JGrasp and Eclipse but shows this when I run the application.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3$CalcButtonListener.actionPerformed(Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3.java:57)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The Code:

```
 /**
 * 
 *@author ngc5043
 *@version 1.0 
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3 extends JFrame
{
private JPanel panel;
private JLabel messageLabel;
private JTextField ExTextField;
private JButton calcButton;
private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 310;
private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 100;


 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3 main = new Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3();
      main.buildPanel();
  }
  public Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3()
  {
    setTitle("Expressions Window");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    buildPanel();
    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
  }

   private void buildPanel()
   {
       messageLabel = new JLabel("Please Enter a Number");
       ExTextField = new JTextField(10);
       calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
       calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
       panel = new JPanel();
       panel.add(messageLabel);
       panel.add(ExTextField);
       panel.add(calcButton);
   }

   private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           String input;
           int num_ent = 0;
           double answerOne;


           input = ExTextField.getText();
           answerOne = Double.parseDouble(input);
           answerOne = num_ent * num_ent;
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Answer Is" + answerOne);

        /**
        * here i would like to add another function. input*(n+1.0)/2.0
        *Getting the same number from the user and calculating this aswell. 
        */ 



       }

   }


}
```

Comment: use JFormatterTextField (with Number instance) or JSpinner, see Oracle tutorials for working code examples

Comment: Thank you for the reply but what I am looking for is for the user to enter one number and have it calculated in two different equations. the number times itself and number*(number+1.0)/2.0 to be displayed in one box after the calculation.

Comment: use this JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Answer Is " + Double.parseDouble(ExTextField.getText())); but you have trouble if you put you know (non number String)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called the buildpanel method twice, Thats why the String was empty, now it turns the string into a double and prints it out:

```
     /**
 * 
 *@author ngc5043
 *@version 1.0 
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3 extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel messageLabel;
    private JTextField ExTextField;
    private JButton calcButton;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 310;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 100;


 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3 main = new Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3();

  }
  public Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3()
  {
      buildPanel();
    setTitle("Expressions Window");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
  }

   private void buildPanel()
   {
       messageLabel = new JLabel("Please Enter a Number");
       ExTextField = new JTextField(10);
       calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");

       panel = new JPanel();
       panel.add(messageLabel);
       panel.add(ExTextField);
       panel.add(calcButton);
       calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
   }

   private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           String input;
           int num_ent = 0;


           input = ExTextField.getText();

           System.out.println(input);

           double answerOne = Double.parseDouble(input);
           System.out.println(answerOne);
           answerOne = num_ent * num_ent;
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Answer Is" + answerOne);

        /**
        * here i would like to add another function. input*(n+1.0)/2.0
        *Getting the same number from the user and calculating this aswell. 
        */ 



       }

   }


}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `ExtTextField` referenced in the `actionPerformed` method is not the one the user is seeing on the screen, because it's been recreated in the `main()` method's call to `buildPanel()`. Good catch.

Comment: @DavidMoles Thanks. Exactly, this was a tricky one, took 20 min to find that the method was invoked twice :P

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I thought main create it when it was called. I am confusing so many things here but slowly they are getting cleared up.

Comment: @ngcarabajal No problem! Swing is tricky but great for learning. Please mark as answer if you think it works ;) Good luck ! :)

Answer (score 1):

This line:
           answerOne = Double.parseDouble(input);
is throwing an exception because input is empty.

If you check here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html
search for parseDouble and you will find the following in the documentation:
**NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.**

If you check your stacktrace, you will see this:
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)

That's how you know where's the problem.

My suggestion is to use something like NetBeans or Eclipse to help you locate the line numbers when the code throws an exception and debug it line by line to see the content of the variables changing.

Use Try/Catch around the line:

```
input = ExTextField.getText();
```

Or make a check in the input, like isNumber(input)

That way you will avoid this kind of unexpected bug.

I hope that helps! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code. It does two things: catch `NumberFormatException` if the input is not a number, and add an `answerTwo` variable which gets calculated and concatenated to the answer display string.

```
private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    String input = ExTextField.getText();
    try  {
      double num_ent = Double.parseDouble(input);
      double answerOne = num_ent * num_ent;
      double answerTwo = num_ent * (num_ent + 1.0) / 2.0;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Answers are " + answerOne + " and " + answerTwo);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input " + input);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I had to change the 'int' in 'num_ent' to a double so that it would compile correctly. The biggest problem I had was defining the integer the user entered and with this piece of code I can see it a lot better.

Comment: You're welcome :) I corrected my answer to reflect the same. If my answer helped you solve your problem, please [accept it!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/236612)

Answer (score 0):

The exception stack shows that a java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String arises which inherits from the java.lang.Double.parseDouble method.
The Java documention ([public static double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)) writes that NumberFormatException is thrown "if the string does not contain a parsable double".

So, the problem is that a button's action handler is called but the textbox does not contain any parsable value. To solve this problem you have to handle the thrown exception. A possible solution is the following:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String input;
    int num_ent = 0;
    double answerOne;

    input = ExTextField.getText();
    try
    {
        answerOne = Double.parseDouble(input);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
    { 
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bad or empty input field");
       return;
    }
    //...
}
```